# Echo string in tcsh with special characters escaped

Tags: shell, environment-variables, tcsh, escaping

Is it possible to echo out a string in tcsh such that it is fully escaped, as tcsh would understand? In the same way as printf %q works in bash:

```
% # Create a variable containing a tab character
% MYMONKEY=$'my\tmonkey'
% printf %q "$MYMONKEY"
$'my\tmonkey'
```

Which can then be used to re-input the variable into bash. Anyone know of anything similar in tcsh?

Comment: I've usually had to write a filter program (sed script) for just such a purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround idea:

in tcsh

> set  MYMONKEY="my\tmonkey"

**Note** you do not add a "\n" at the end so the output will reflect this decision:

```
 printf "%s" $MYMONKEY
 my\tmonkey_My_Login_Name_@myhost>

 to fix it you can use 

 printf "%s\n" $MYMONKEY
 my\tmonkey
 _My_Login_Name_@myhost>
```

or

```
 printf $MYMONKEY
 my      monkey_My_Login_Name_@myhost>_

 echo $MYMONKEY
 my      monkey
 _My_Login_Name_@myhost>_
```